# Including PHP & JavaScript functions from other files

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a fairly large (in contrast to what I've made in the past) web based system at the moment. It features a lot of PHP and JavaScript work where at the moment I have numerous functions in both.

I've always gone by the route of have any functions that you're going to use on a page as a separate file that is included in the page and that function then called. This way if you wanted to use the function on a different page, you're not writing out the function on two pages.

Eg. "index.php" including "scripts.php" and echoing the result of a function in "scripts.php"

Now, I have a fairly complicated scenario where I have 6+ functions which different combinations of which ones will be required on a few different pages depending on their purpose. For Example; I'd have 'page 1' requiring functions 2,3 and 6. 'page 2' requiring functions 2,4,5 and 6. 'page 3' requiring functions 1,2,3 and 5.

In this scenario is it better practice to;

A) Have all of the individual functions on separate files and only include the files with functions required on each page on a page-by-page basis.

or

B) Have all of the individual functions on one file that is included on each page even though half the functions won't be called.

or

C) Something I haven't considered

Comment: SO is not a design discussion forum. It's for narrowly-scoped questions that can have objectively correct answers. That said, a separate file for every function seems crazy to me.

Comment: Group the related functions together. Don't worry much about including including a few extra functions that you don't use. Maybe organize stuff into classes.

Comment: If you developed it in a certain way, [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) would be the tool to use. I imagine some form of webpack or gulp scripting could also build out your use cases, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to look at using an "object orientated" approach rather than "procedural".

This site has some good examples:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Then look at autoloading with composer:

http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer

Comment: I might start with the PHP manual and the PSR- 4 standard before moving on to Composer.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to include more functions than you need in PHP - the additional cost incurred is parsing the extra PHP which is miniscule (and this can later be optimized by caching the bytecode).

You should group your functions based on their functionality (preferably in classes) - eg., DB accessors, Redis/Memcache methods, image manipulation methods, and so on and so forth.

You might benefit greatly by either using a framework (eg. Laravel, CodeIgniter etc.) or spending some time reading their documentation and seeing how they structure their code. Frameworks are great in helping you organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the pragmatic sense, putting all your functions in one file is not a problem. But, from experience, there may be a day when you have many `require` / `include` statements spread across multiple files.

### Option C

If you stretch yourself to use [PHP namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) make [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for your functions, you can create an autoloader system.

I learned how to do it by using the PHP Manual on [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), and the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards page.

Switching to object oriented programming may be overkill, but keep it in mind as an option when *the world* starts to get too big.

Sincerely,

Anthony Rutledge